# Android Activity disappearing - Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I never experienced this, what's going wrong?

I have a launch Activity A that starts another Activity B (forResult). Then when I hit the home button, both go onPause. When I go back to my app via the Android App- chooser (or whatever it's called, when you longpress the home button), Activity B gets destroyed.

How can I resume Activity B instead?

Comment: Activity B and manifest needed to find solution...

Comment: I'm sorry I dont get it.

Comment: code required to see that....

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it sounds like you encountered with a known issue: [Activity stack behaves incorrectly during the first run of an app when started from Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373).

Also check this issue (this is actually the same issue, but reported by another user): [App launch fundamentally broken when app is launched via browser, market install or market update](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658).